# In Ireport 4.7.1 , socket creation error is coming while connecting to database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, hsqldb, ireport

I am trying to connect to SQL server management studio from ireport 4.7.1 . But I am getting 'socket creation error' . I tried to connect with hsqldb driver .

Do I need to download and import the jars related to MS-SQL , as I am using SSMS ?

Or is there any other way to solve socket creation error.

Comment: sqlserver tag added

Comment: Do you have an instance of SQL Server installed somewhere? SSMS, SQL Server Management Studio, is a client that connects to SQL Server instances to manage them - it doesn't provide SQL Server connectivity to other applications.